# Booting a PC to disk partition format tool

Tags: windows, usb, partitioning

I often need to format a partition disks on my windows based machines. At the moment I do this by using a Win 7 install CD and going as far as the custom install page. Is there an easier way to get to some sort of partitioning tool, the CD takes a long time to boot and not all of our PCs have optical drives. Maybe some way of bootinh from USB key?

Answer (score 2):

Parted Magic will do what you want, http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start

It is a Live CD which can be put on to a USB Stick using Unetbootin, http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I would use [uNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make a live USB of [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) and use the utilities therein to format the disk. You could also try Darik's Boot and Nuke ([DBAN](http://www.dban.org/))
 but I don't know if this would do partitions only.

Answer (score 0):

Most commercial partition tools come with a boot disk, or the ability to create one.

[Partition Manager](http://www.partition-manager.com/)

[Partition Commander](http://www.avanquest.com/USA/software/partition-commander-11-126553)

[Disk Director](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/)

Answer (score 0):

USB bootable Linux with `cfdisk` works just fine, if you don't have to move/downsize/upsize already used partitions. For these trickier tasks, take Partition Magic.